# Whether we can generate a url from a page source?

Tags: html

I know this question is weird, but anyway I want to know it,

In web browsers or generally we can know the `page source` of a url, but I had some page source (HTML Code) and now I don't know the url of that page source. Can we generate a url from that page source or is there a way or anything that we can do to get a url from the page source?

When I searched I am getting `page source from a url`, so I am asking here.

Comment: [Hint](https://www.google.com/search?q=In+web+browsers+or+generally+we+can+know+the+page+source+of+a+url+%2C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If @Wex is headed in the right direction with his answer and based on your comment then I'll answer with this.

You can get the "Web Developers Toolbar" add-on for FireFox which has an option to "View Generated Source"

[image]

this is the same a selecting the whole page and using "View Selected Source" in FF. This will give you the DOM of that page including javascript render code.

If you're asking if there is a way to get the original url from source code the answer is no. Why? Because Google doesn't search the source code, it searches content. There also could be a thousand different websites that use pieces of that code.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, you can view the source of any webpage by preceding the url with `view-source:`. As far as I know, this is the only browser that allows you to do this; Safari and Firefox for instance, shows the source in a popup window which can't be accessed in a regular window.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply, if we want to view the page source, we can proceed as u stated above, but i had some page source(HTML) generated by executing some javascript functions, and now is there a way to generate a url from that page source